# Index in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, b-tree

How can be totalKeysExamined and totalDocsExamined can be same ?
[image]
Like in this B-tree when we want to search for index 12 . Then the index sequence followed first will be left of 13 then right of (9, 11) then finally we get 12 so the no of keys examined are three and document to be accessed .

So can someone please explain me concept of totalKeysExamined and totalDocsExamined in detail and easy way ?

Answer (score 0):

The fields `totalKeysExamined` and `totalDocsExamined` are well explained in the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/ you should read through it there. It does not make sense to copy all the examples into my answer.

`totalKeysExamined`:  Indicates the number of scanned indexed entries. In your example if you would search for value = 12, it would return just 1, because only one entry matches with the value = 12. It does not take into account how may entires you need to pass in the storing data structure, **just counts how may documents match the indexed filter condition**.

`totalDocsExamined`: Indicates the number of examined documents. If the values is the same as the `totalKeysExamined`, this means your query has a good coverage by the index (filter condition is indexed) but e.g. other fields have to be examined as well to fulfill another filter condition or simply the complete document has to be loaded for the requested result.